# How to insert extra column with data in #each loop?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, each

I have the following template:

```
<body>
  <table border="1px">
  {{> test}}
  <table>
</body>

<template name="test">
  {{#each items}}
  <tr>
        {{> test2}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="test2">
   <td>{{name}}</td><td>{{lastruntime}}</td><td>{{result}}</td><td>{{blaat}}</td>
</template>
```

And the following client-side code:

```
ScheduledTasks = new Meteor.Collection("scheduledTasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.test.items = function () {
    return ScheduledTasks.find({});
  }
};
```

Now **{{blaat}}** is not part of the document, but needs to be filled with data based on the data in the individual row. I tried a lot, but cannot find out how to access/fill the **{{blaat}}** tag. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](http://docs.meteor.com/#map) to  modify each document by adding a `blaat` property. Then you can return the array of modified documents, instead of returning a cursor. For example:

```js
Template.test.items = function() {
  return ScheduledTasks.find().map(function(item) {
    item.blaat = item.name + item.result;
    return item;
  });
};
```

The `blaat` property will then be available to your template, just like `name` and `result`.

Alternatively, if you thought the `blaat` property should **always** be present whenever you retrieve a scheduled task, then you could consider adding a [transofrm](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-transforming-collection-documents) to the collection.